# How to fix "npm install -g firebase-tools" problem on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: firebase

Who can fix this problem?

```
npm ERR! Error: Method Not Allowed
npm ERR!     at errorResponse (/usr/share/npm/lib/cache/add-named.js:260:10)
npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/cache/add-named.js:203:12
npm ERR!     at saved (/usr/share/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/get.js:167:7)
npm ERR!     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:135:15)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Linux 4.14.98+
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "firebase-tools"
npm ERR! cwd /home/pi
npm ERR! node -v v8.11.1
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.21
npm ERR! code E405
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/pi/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: Hi @Chawki Zouari, did you find a solution to your problem? I have the same.

Comment: Wow! I just tried 'sudo' before the call and it started to download. Got other errors though during the process! This is strange that the other npm install worked without 'sudo'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is "Method Not Allowed" which is a 405 HTTP error. You are using a version of npm that's been deprecated and the npm service no longer supports (I recommend at least version 5.x.x of npm).

You need to upgrade to the latest version of npm with `sudo npm install -g npm` to fix it.

Comment: Hi @Zobia Kanwal, how can you update to version 5+ within Raspbian? I did what you asked and the version stays at 1.4.21

Comment: Hi @David please try this.   `sudo npm update -g npm`   and let me know with screenshot of the output or error if you get any.

Answer (score 0):

Here my suggestion to you

- sudo su -
- apt-get remove npm -y
- apt-get install npm -y
- node -v should be the same as yours
- npm -v should be at least 6.9.0